# Enabling/Disabling checkbox field with Angular2

Tags: jquery, angular, angular2-forms

I am dynamically rendering the checkbox and combobox fields and performing following functionality:

1. based on the API response, if the checkbox field appears as selected then combobox appears as enable else it would be disable.
2. If user select checkbox field then combo box should be enable else disabled

The combo box fields works work for the first case but not working in the second case. The state (enable or disable) cannot changes later on.

Here is my template snippet:

```
 < tr *ngFor="let widgetAttribute of _preferencesWidget">

 < td *ngFor="let subattribute of widgetAttribute.methods">

 < select *ngIf="subattribute.name == 'Email' && subattribute.type == 'LIST'" id="{{subattribute.name}}Check" class="selectpicker" data-max-options="1" (change)="validateCombo($event)"
                                                            [disabled]="!subattribute.enabled">
                                                                <option *ngFor="let subValue of subattribute.values" value="{{subValue.code}}" [selected]="subValue.code == subattribute.selected">{{subValue.description}}< /option>
                                                            < /select>
 < /td>
< /tr>
```

> The generated id for checkbox is : **InformationCheck** and for combobox is : **pensionMCheck**

My component logic is:

```
 public validateCombo() {

     if (this.pensionCheck) {
         $('#pensionMCheck').prop('disabled', false);
         if ($('#pensionMCheck').val() === 'Y') {
             this.pensionMCheck = true;
         } else {
             this.pensionMCheck = false;
         }
    } else {
         this.pensionMCheck = false;
         $('#pensionMCheck').val('N');
         $('#pensionMCheck').prop('disabled', true);
         $('#pensionMCheck').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the checkbox status to a property (`isChecked`) and bind `enabled` of `<select>` to the same property:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked">
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" [enabled]="!isChecked"
```

Comment: I am able to resolve it. Code is working fine the only problem is that there is duplicate element exists in the DOM tree.

Comment: What duplicate element? You mean multiple select elements? What problem does it cause?

Comment: No, the the ID that a element is getting dynamically is duplicated with another element.

Comment: Are you talking about `id="{{subattribute.name}}Check"`?

Comment: I don't know. If `name` is different for each `subattribute, then there shouldn't be duplicates.